# python,django - can i call save directly in views ? i hav array,from which only some keys need to be saved,so automation or manual?

Tags: python, django

I am beginner to python Django . I have a string in json format , like

```
jsondict = {"name": "value", "pwd": "pwdvalue", "email": "email@gmail.com"}
```

i converted it to **dict** using json.loads(str)

From the above dict, i want to save only name,and pwd and many others except some keys. So, i am doing like this in the views  :

```
u=users(name=jsondict['name'], pwd=jsondict['pwd'])
u.save()
```

Is my code having good quality ?   or do i need to do that in any other way for  having good quality .
In my question,automatic or manual in the sense, do i have to insert some dict directly or manullay have to do as i shown in the code ?
Will provide more information if necessary
Thanks

Comment: What happen if you simply do: user(**jsondict)

Comment: @jgomo3: You will get a TypeError from an unexpected keyword argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option you have here is to filter your dict down, and then use `**` to unpack it as keyword arguments.

```
user_fields = {"name", "pwd"}
jsondict= {"name":"value","pwd":"pwdvalue","email":"email@gmail.com"}
userdict = {key: value for (key, value) in jsondict.items() if key in user_fields}
u = users(**userdict)
```

We use a [dict comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY) to filter out everything but the values we want (stored in the set `user_fields`).

Comment: thanks for the answer . is the next line u.save() ? and does that work without writing custom methods for save() ?

Comment: That's all entirely dependant on Django and what `users()` is. This will not affect the way that class functions. If you want it to function as your code did before, yes, you will need to do `u.save()`.

Comment: Or, as per Burhan Khalid's comment, apparently `u = User.objects.create(**userdict)` [will do the same as creating, then saving](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create).